Confusion understanding series/parallel relationship of mechanical components of a DC motor in Simulink Simscape
After watching this youtube video, I am trying to implement Simscape model of a DC motor in simulink - see snapshots below.
I understand from both photos that the electrical components' resistance and  inductance are in series with each other and the electromechanical converter, but I am confused by the series/parallel relationship of mechanical components, inertia, and rotational damper and their relationship with the electromechanical converter. According to my understanding of simscape, damper rotational electromechanical converter are in parallel with each other and this parallel combination is in series with inertia. But i am confused by the schematic diagram, is there same series parallel relationship like that in simscape?



Your second picture may be a brushed DC motor with a fixed field provided by a coil instead of a permanent magnet. I wouldn't pay too much attention to this personally, it's not even in your simscape snapshot.
If you're having issues visualising series and parallel for the mechanical part of the diagram, get back to the basics: in electrical circuits, we define ground as an arbitrary reference from which we measure potential (~"voltage"), and then current flows through branches. Simscape kind of follows the same logic for all physical quantities, but as a result it has to define types of nets first. The yellow net you see here is a rotation net, so its value is an angle - but with respect to what? Well, with respect to your arbitrary reference which is "Mechanical rotation reference".
Then everything flows: your rotational electromechanical converter acts like a "controlled voltage source", but for rotation, so it will "turn" its "R" net/node with respect to its "C" (for case I guess?) net/node, which is 0 rotation here, under the effect of the voltage you apply from the electrical side (and as you know, this will show a voltage on the electrical side that will converge to an equilibrium we call "operating point").
The "R" net is also tied to an inertia, but inertia only applies to a part, a net - it doesn't have a reference.
The damper does need to be connected to two locations like the electromechanical converter: it resists rotation, but reacting on what? On its "C" net/node, which here again is the mechanical rotation reference.
So basically both the damper and the electromechanical converter "react" on the same part, which could be a chassis of some kind and is taken here as the 0 reference for rotation. The inertia applies to a part only, without reference. Then only, when you step back, you see the damper is in parallel with the electromechanical converter. If you draw a diagram of masses and springs by hand, the inertia COULD be seen as in series with something else (although it's not because in series means there are nets on boths sides and inertia is a net/part property), but there is nothing connected on the other side of that part.
You may be interested in looking at how the thermal nodal models are made, it is very useful for electronic circuits and follows the same logic, with the difference that thermal inertia is captured by a property of a capacitor referenced to ground instead of a property of the net itself.
Simscape excels at treating very different physical quantities in the same way, I suggest you try out other types of physical quantities to see the pattern - it should make things clearer.

Your second picture may be a brushed DC motor with a fixed field provided by a coil instead of a permanent magnet. I wouldn't pay too much attention to this personally, it's not even in your simscape snapshot.
You mean motor type is different in simscape and schematic?
